# Geração números aleatórios C++

Tags: c++

Olá, estou escrevendo uma simulação em C++ e tenho que gerar alguns números aleatórios. Para isso, inicializo ( srand(time(NULL)) ) uma vez apenas e tenho um método da seguinte forma:

```
void Supermercado::geraTempoProximoCliente() {
    int intervaloProximoCliente = rand()%(2*tempoMedioChegada-1) +1;

    printf("Intervalo para chegar outro cliente %d\n",intervaloProximoCliente);

    tempoChegadaProximoCliente = getRelogio() + intervaloProximoCliente;
}
```

Alguém saberia me dizer porque cada vez que meu programa gera um intervalo novo, ele é sempre o mesmo durante toda a execução do programa? Construtor onde a semente é gerada:

```
Supermercado::Supermercado(string nome_,int tempoSimulacao_,inttempoMedioChegada_,
    int numeroDeCaixas_, int tamanhoMaximoDasFilas, Caixa caixas[]) {
listaDeCaixas = new CircularList<Caixa>();
tempoMedioChegada = tempoMedioChegada_;
relogio = 0;
clientesDesistentes = 0;
valorDesistentes = 0;
numeroDeCaixas = numeroDeCaixas_;
tempoSimulacao = tempoSimulacao_;
tempoChegadaProximoCliente = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < numeroDeCaixas; i++)
    listaDeCaixas -> push_back(caixas[i]);
}
```

Eu instancio o supermercado uma vez apenas no main e chamo o método executar dele.

O método executar:

```
void Supermercado::executa() {
    bool continua = true;
    Caixa caixa;
    geraTempoProximoCliente();
    while(relogio != tempoSimulacao*3600) {
        if(relogio == tempoChegadaProximoCliente)
            geraTempoProximoCliente();
    }
    relogio++;
}
```

Comment: Onde está gerando a semente? O problema dele ser o local dela.

Comment: Estou gerando no construtor da classe Supermercado, no main eu instancio um Supermercado e chamo o método executar dele. Onde estaria o erro nisso? To quebrando a cabeça nisso

Comment: A não ser que srand deve ser inicializado no método que rand vai ser chamado, mas aí ainda estaria emperrado pois precisaria gerar número aleatórios diferentes a cada chamada do método.

Comment: Coloque o código pra gente ver. Mas parece que o problema é ter colocado no construtor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o construtor do Supermercado.

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir seu problema. http://ideone.com/ao2qah

Comment: Pois é, vendo seu link percebo que o meu método deveria funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Talvez se tentar fazer um [mcve] ou acha o erro por conta própria ou pelo menos dá melhores subsídios para nós ajudarmos.

Comment: Por que nao utilizar a biblioteca Mersenne Twist para gerar os numeros? pra mim o melhor algoritmo de números aleatorios. https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html Só baixar a incluir na pasta do projeto

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Andrey. Foi resolvido, achei um srand perdido no construtor de outra classe que é instanciada toda hora, isso estava causando a repetição do número.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O C++11 já pode ser considerado padrão, e introduziu uma biblioteca padrão para números aleatórios, `<random>`, mesmo que não seja a fonte do seu problema, vou apresentar-lhe.

O principal problema de usar `rand()` e truncar os bits com `%` é que a distribuição dos bits em `rand` não é garantida de ser uniforme. Mesmo que funcione™ no seu caso, eu recomendo usar as novas bibliotecas que garantem a implementação padrão do gerador pseudo-aleatório.

Basicamente, você precisa declarar um gerador de números. Um dos fornecidos pela biblioteca padrão é um Mersenne Twister de 32 bits:

```
#include <random>
std::mt19937 mt(42); //gerador mersene twist, inicializado com seed = 42
```

Depois você precisa definir como quer mapear a saída pseudo-aleatória dele (bem melhor que improvisar com o operador `%`). Se deseja números inteiros entre zero e cem, uniformemente distribuídos, por exemplo:

```
//distribuição linear de inteiros entre 0 e 100
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> linear_i(0, 100);
```

Já se deseja números reais linearmente distribuídos entre 0.0 e 100.0, por exemplo:

```
//distribuição linear de números reais entre 0 e 100
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> linear_r(0.f, 100.f);
```

Depois de inicializados o gerador e a distribuição (você pode guardá-los como um membro da classe), toda vez que você precisar de um número, basta chamar a distribuição desejada para mapear um número gerado pelo gerador:

```
int   aleatorio_i = linear_i( mt ); //inteiro pseudo-aleatório
float aleatorio_f = linear_r( mt ); //float pseudo-aleatório
```

[Você pode testar o exemplo que criei aqui](http://cpp.sh/8mxgv).

O melhor da nova biblioteca é que ela possui várias distribuições prontas. O caso que você apresenta - intervalo entre chegada de clientes - por exemplo, pode ser modelado por uma distribuição normal em torno da média.

[Um tempo atrás fiz um código exemplo das distribuições](http://cpp.sh/7rbq6). Talvez sirva de guia.

Answer (score -1):

Sempre coloque função *srand()* antes da função *rand()*.
Como você chama o *rand()* em

```
void Supermercado::geraTempoProximoCliente()
```

Então coloque o *srand()* antes do código

```
int intervaloProximoCliente = rand()%(2*tempoMedioChegada-1) +1;
```

Fincando assim:

```
void Supermercado::geraTempoProximoCliente() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int intervaloProximoCliente = rand()%(2*tempoMedioChegada-1) +1;
    printf("Intervalo para chegar outro cliente %d\n",intervaloProximoCliente);
    tempoChegadaProximoCliente = getRelogio() + intervaloProximoCliente;
}
```

Fazendo isso, você garante que toda vez que gerar um numero novo, o programa captura um novo horário do sistema para usar na função *rand()*.

**Espero ter ajudado!**

Answer (score -1):

Use `srand(time(0))` em vez de `srand(time(NULL))`. Vê se funciona.